# IIS proxy reverse

Tags: reactjs, iis, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

Pay attention to the following examples.

```
subdomain1.sample.com => target.sample.com/1001
subdomain1.sample.com/order => target.sample.com/1001/order
subdomain1.sample.com/login => target.sample.com/1001/login

subdomain2.sample.com => target.sample.com/1002
subdomain2.sample.com/order => target.sample.com/1002/order
subdomain2.sample.com/login => target.sample.com/1002/login
```

A `reactjs` project is running on `target.sample.com`, which is as follows

```
/          ==>‌ page not found
/:id       ==> home
/:id/login ==> page login
/:id/order ==> page order
```

We want to do this in IIS with the help of proxy reverse or rewrite.

Below are the settings of the **web.config** file related to the **subdomain1.sample.com** address

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="http_to_https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="proxy" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://target.sample.com/1001/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^https://target.sample.com/1001/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="https://subdomain1.sample.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" path="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

such an error can be seen in the browser console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at main.697bcedd.js:1:1)
```

Have I gone the wrong way? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can trace down to every details behind the scene with FRT, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: This link should help you slove this issue: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr).